# Load domain cookies by XHR Request

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, xmlhttprequest

When I send an XHR Request to an URL, how can I get the Cookies in my PHP Script:

Example:

```
var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open("POST", 'http://127.0.0.1/index.php', true);
```

And for http://127.0.0.1 I have a lot of cookies. But when the request is send, then I can not catch the cookies.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are setting the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

It practicaly not possible to get the cookies form the browser with XHR Request like this obove, because the call is going direct to the server but the cookies are in the browser.

The only way to do this is to generate an Iframe in similar way:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.frameBorder = 0;
iframe.width = 1;
iframe.height = 1;
iframe.name= "stlconv";
iframe.scrolling = "no";
iframe.allowtransparency = "true";
iframe.vspace = "0";
iframe.hspace = "0";
iframe.marginwidth = "0";
iframe.marginheight = "0";
iframe.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

In this case you have an HTML element opened in the browser again and you can catch the cookies.